# Как проверить, является ли текст ссылкой?

Tags: python, бот, aiogram

Алгоритм работает так:

1. Пользователь пишет в чат ссылку
2. Бот проверяет, если это ссылка, то сохраняет её.

На самом деле мне нужно подгружать материал из instagram по этой ссылке. Я так думаю, дальше это делается через `webhook` или `wget`, буду благодарен, если примерную реализацию кто-нибудь сможет показать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего мне кажется регулярками:

```py
import re
mydata = "Какойто текст https://yandex.ru/ и еще текст https://ya.ru/"
l = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", mydata).group()
print(l) # https://yandex.ru/
```

Или вернуть список всех url если их несколько:

```
import re
mydata = "Какойто текст https://yandex.ru/ и еще текст https://ya.ru/"
l = re.findall("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", mydata)
print(l) # ['https://yandex.ru/', 'https://ya.ru/']
```

Comment: Чрезмерно благодарен! Спасибо!)

Comment: yandex.ru (без протокола) не найдет

Comment: @Jack_oS Учитывая что регулярка составлена на https то и не должен. Другой вопрос что определение  `yandex.ru` в тексте породит ложные срабатывания. Например: `Какойто текст.Новое предложение`. В любом случае регулярку всегда можно подогнать под личные нужды.